# Basic query on Mysql Insert Statement

Tags: mysql, insert

I have N number of records in a table ,i wanna move all records from one table other say old table as `table1`  and new as `table2` .I have a query with sub query to select the records from the table for insertion .
Assuming as 10000 records While inserting on 6000 record it gets some exception in it , it got to an end,but still the `table2` is empty , Here i wanna know that is the 5999 records where it would have been inserted  in a databse ?

Thanks in advance ,,

if its unworthy to answer or any cause let me know the reason to down vote i can improve it

Answer (score 1):

> I have a query with sub query to select the records from the table for insertion

I assume you have some `INESRT INTO table2(<COLUMN LIST>) SELECT <COLUMN LIST> FROM table1 WHERE ...` that you are running to move the records.

If so, the INSERT statement is run as part of a transaction and will be committed only if the statement is executed successfully, i.e. if it is able to `INSERT` all the records returned by that `SELECT` query. Otherwise, the transaction gets rolled back and no records will be inserted.

> Here i wanna know that is the 5999 records where it would have been inserted in a database?

These records would have been inserted into the worktable in tmp location while executing the `INSERT` statement. It would have been committed to the main table if everything had gone well.